# Saving a dynamically created Image to a File.

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

I have an image, I read the image, add a few things to image (like some text etc).

All this I do inside a `JPanel`.

Now, I want to save the resulting image to a *.png file*.

I think, there is a way to do this for a buffered image using `ImageIO.write()`

But I cannot convert the dynamically created image to a BufferedImage.

Is there a way I can go about this ?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690275/exporting-a-jpanel-to-an-image/17690351#17690351)

Comment: I tried using: BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
But all the values for the transparency parameter kept on giving an exception saying "Unknown Image type".

Comment: You'd need to provide a runnable example before I would even be able to guess why.  The example I linked works just fine...

Comment: Convert your image into BufferedImage.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605248/java-converting-image-to-bufferedimage

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class.

It will create a BufferedImage of your JPanel. The class also has code to write the image to a file.

Answer (score 2):

> All this I do inside a `JPanel`.

Do it instead in another `BufferedImage` displayed in a `JLabel`.  The code can get a `Graphics2D` object using `BufferedImage.createGraphics()` method.  Paint the image and text to the new `Graphics2D` instance and you then the new image can be saved directly, along with changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use Following method it worked for me...

```
void TakeSnapShot(JPanel panel,String Locatefile){  
           BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(panel.getSize().width,  panel.getSize().height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  

           panel.paint(bi.createGraphics()); 

           File image = new File(Locatefile);  
        try{  
            image.createNewFile();  
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", image);
        }catch(Exception ex){  
        }  
    }
```